# @Html.DropDownListFor - How to append extra <option> to list

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, html.dropdownlistfor

I have the following in my view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Category, new SelectList(Model.categories, "Id", "Name", Model.Category), "All", new { @class = "form-control" })

<select name="Category" id="Category">
 <option value="">All</option>
 <option value="1">Debug</option>
 <option value="2" selected="selected">Error</option>
</select>
```

In my repo I get the values as follows:

```
    public IEnumerable<Category> GetCategories()
    {
        return _context.Category.ToList();
    }
```

How do I give `All` a value of 0 instead of empty string?

Is there any way to append it to my repo method below as I'd like to keep my controller clean.

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetCategoriesSelectList()
    {

        return _context.Category
             .Select(s => new SelectListItem
             {
                 Value = s.Id.ToString(),
                 Text = s.Name
             }).ToList();


    }
```

***UPDATE ***

I've found the following helper but cant figure out how to use it:

```
 public static SelectList AddFirstItem(SelectList origList, SelectListItem firstItem)
    {
        List<SelectListItem> newList = origList.ToList();
        newList.Insert(0, firstItem);

        var selectedItem = newList.FirstOrDefault(item => item.Selected);
        var selectedItemValue = String.Empty;
        if (selectedItem != null)
        {
            selectedItemValue = selectedItem.Value;
        }

        return new SelectList(newList, "Value", "Text", selectedItemValue);
    }
```

In my view I have :

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Category, Helpers.AddFirstItem(new SelectList(Model.categories, "Id", "Name", Model.Category), "All"), null, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

What do I pass in as the second argument - the above doesnt work?

Comment: Create your `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` in the controller and append a new `SelectListItem` with `Text = "All"` and `Value = "0"` to it

Comment: @ozzii if you dont want to have any problem with the database integrity ,foreign key violations and all, I suggest you add the needed options , directly into the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your `SelectList` in the controller that includes a `SelectListItem` with `Text = "All"` and `Value = "0"`, for example

```
IEnumerable<SelectListItem> categories = new List<SelectListItem>
{
    new SelectListItem() {Value = "0", Text = "All" }

}.Concat(GetCategories().Select(x => new SelectListItem
{
    Value = x.Id.ToString(),
    Text = x.Name
});
```

and then pas it to the view, ideally in a view model property, but you could use `ViewBag`

```
ViewBag.CategoryList = categories;
```

and in the view

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Category,(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.CategoryList, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: Note, if you do not want the code in your controller, just refactor it into a separate method

Comment: I get error `List<SelectListItem>` does not contain a difinition for Value`

Comment: Oops sorry, forgot to ad it. See edit Note also I assumed you wanted "All" first, but you can swap them - `GetCategories()` first, then `.Concat()` the new item

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetCategoriesSelectList()
{

    return _context.Category
         .Select(s => new SelectListItem
         {
             Value = s.Id.ToString(),
             Text = s.Name
         }).ToList().Add(new SelectListItem() { Text="all",Value="0" });


}
```